# can not define `const string CrLf = Environment.NewLine;`

Tags: c#, constants

why c# compiler does not compiles this code:

```
const string CrLfTab = Environment.NewLine;
```

I'm formatting a `SQL` script, and need newline for more human understandable syntax in log.

Comment: `readonly string CrLfTab = Environment.NewLine;`

Comment: I can't say for sure, but (guessing about it) new lines are platform-dependent - so for .net core code to be cross platform, this value must be provided at runtime based on the OS the code is running on, not at compile time (based on the OS the code is being compiled on).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `const` since `Environment.NewLine` is a property which is *not known* on *compile time* (`Environment.NewLine` can be `"\r"`, `"\r\n"`, `"\n"` depending on platform where your program runs).

You can, however, use `readonly` field:

```
readonly static string CrLfTab = Environment.NewLine;
```

or readonly property:

```
static string CrLfTab {get;} = Environment.NewLine;
```